# How Read Response Promise value from a get service (Springboot) in React?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot

i'm new in reactjs:
I have a springboot with one service that return a ResponseEntity like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/startTest") 
public ResponseEntity<String> runTest {

    String response;
    if (this.values>0){
        response=String.format("Test Failed: %s", summary.getFailures().get(0).getException().getMessage());
    }
    else{
        response="Test Successfull!";
    }

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(response);
```

In react I have this function for read body:

```
    var url = "http://127.22.22.12:8090/startTest";
    await fetch(url)
        .then(function(response){return response.json();})
        .then(function(data){const items=data;
                             console.log(items)
        })
```

but i have this error in console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
```

if write console.log(response.text()) i view Promise OBJECT but how get PROMISE VALUE as a Text?

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You're using [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) in your code. You don't need to chain promises.
Try this

```
 var url = "http://127.22.22.12:8090/startTest";
 const result = await fetch(url)
 console.log(result.text())
```

Also, your fetch function should be an `async` function in order to use async await.

Comment: yes but i dont get Text.. I view this:
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://127.1.1.12:8090/startTest/Test/Test.SmartRoadApiTest.VehicleDataTest/AP0000009", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}

Comment: what is the type of result that you get? you should be able to use it by  console.log(result.json())

Comment: Response type "corse" i need take body as Text.. like Sping Boot Response

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
If you see springboot function i put a String in body:
 return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(response);

Comment: if your backend sends string, use console.log(result.text())